# ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

---

i'm trying to train a resnet model, my code is below:

```
resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
for param in resnet.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

import torch.nn as nn
n_inputs = resnet.fc.in_features
resnet.fc = nn.Linear(n_inputs,5)
```

^ here i just imported the model

then i imported my images like so:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import csv
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array,array_to_img, load_img,save_img
import cv2 
ImageNameDataHash = {}
global ImageNameDataHash
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Dataset'
directories = ['train/1', 'test/1', 'val/1']
for dir in directories: 
  images = os.listdir(os.path.join(path,dir))
  print("Number of files in " + dir + " is " + str(len(images)))
  for imageFileName in tqdm(images):
    imgFullPath = os.path.join(path,dir,imageFileName)
    img = load_img(imgFullPath)
    arr = img_to_array(img)
    del(img)
    arr = cv2.resize(arr, (224,224))
    arr = cv2.addWeighted(arr,4,cv2.GaussianBlur(arr,(0,0),10),-4,128) / 255.0
    print(arr.shape)
    print(arr.shape)
    ImageNameDataHash[str(imageFileName)] = arr
    del(arr)
```

then finally put all my data into one dataframe that looks like this

```
index   image       data
802 4232_left   [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
334 762_right   [[[0.50148463, 0.5013814, 0.50132805], [0.5014...
1190    5319_right  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
633 3940_left   [[[0.49936426, 0.4985614, 0.4992031], [0.49936...
345 783_right   [[[0.50195587, 0.5019481, 0.50195193], [0.5019...
... ... ...
167 492_left    [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
463 963_left    [[[0.5018181, 0.5018181, 0.5018181], [0.501817...
609 3907_left   [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
1498    7182_right  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
1162    5220_left   [[[0.5018678, 0.5018602, 0.5018561], [0.501860...
```

where data is the image data

```
model = Model(resnet)
# Set Optimizer
from keras.optimizers import adam

opt = adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=3,batch_size = 20)
```

when I try to fit my model, I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-e2b53994c24f> in <module>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=3,batch_size = 20)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    495                                      'either a single '
    496                                      'array or a list of arrays. '
--> 497                                      'You passed: x=' + str(x))
    498                 all_inputs.append(x)
    499 

ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=           image                                               data
802    4232_left  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
334    762_right  [[[0.50148463, 0.5013814, 0.50132805], [0.5014...
1190  5319_right  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
633    3940_left  [[[0.49936426, 0.4985614, 0.4992031], [0.49936...
345    783_right  [[[0.50195587, 0.5019481, 0.50195193], [0.5019...
...          ...                                                ...
167     492_left  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
463     963_left  [[[0.5018181, 0.5018181, 0.5018181], [0.501817...
609    3907_left  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
1498  7182_right  [[[0.5019608, 0.5019608, 0.5019608], [0.501960...
1162   5220_left  [[[0.5018678, 0.5018602, 0.5018561], [0.501860...

[1057 rows x 2 columns]
```

I don't get it, is there something wrong with how i'm passing my data? or what is the issue here? i can't figure out for the life of me.

Comment: what is your x and y shape? It should not be `1057 rows x 2 columns` X should be `no of samples * resolution * channels`

Comment: can you give me an example of how it should look? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @Iam, how did you create `X_train` and `Y_train` variable?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath I split my df into X & Y (x for features [name and img] and y for label) then I used train_test_split twice, once to get X_train & Y_train and once again to get X_test, Y_test, X_val, and Y_val

Comment: @Iam, I can see you are using `cv2.resize(arr, (224,224))` hence your input should be `no_of_images * 224 * 224 * 3(channels)`. You should consider only `img arr` for feature not image name.make sure all the image having same resolution.

Comment: @NarendraPrasath sorry I don't really get what you mean by `no_of_images * 224 * 224 * 3(channels)` do you mean i should change the input type of the network or transform my own input to this? if i were to change my input it would be `1057 * 224 * 224 *3` but how can i pass that to the network with no reference to the data itself? sorry this is one of my first projects i'm a little lost. thank u so much

Comment: @Iam, Yes, this would be the correct dimension of your input `1057 * 224 * 224 *3`. What reference do you need to pass? We supposed to pass `Y_train` as label of the each individual image. e.g: `1057*1`. `X_train`  should be numpy multidimension array

Comment: @Iam, you should use `ImageDataGenerator` for loading images from the directory. but it would expect that directory structure as class label folder name for storing images.

Comment: @NarendraPrasath so if i drop the image name column, and change X_train to X_train.to_numpy() it would work?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath my data is all in one folder, it's not divided into class folders

Comment: `ImageDataGenerator` works more efficiently and it won't load all the images into RAM directly in one go. While doing processing, it will load individual images. It would be better if you organize your folder structure and use `ImageDataGenerator` directly.

Comment: Try `X_train.to_numpy()` this and make sure your dimensions are correct.